# Why is there a difference between OpenAI API tokenization and Spacy or Sci-kit Learn tokenization?

Tags: nlp, spacy, openai-api

In *Spacy* the tokenization is by word or sentences, while in *OpenAI API* they divide words into tokens and even take spaces or punctuation marks into account.
Why do they do this? Is it to charge you more and have better control with different languages? In the case of languages with words larger than others. Or is there some other reason?

Comment: I think you are referring to the Subword Tokenization technique which is commonly used in large language models. Is [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tokenizer_summary#subword-tokenization) helpful for you?

Comment: Yes, that is the name of the technique I was looking for. Thank you